# Block back button in a browser like whatsapp web

Tags: javascript, ajax

I develop a single page web application, i want to block back button to prevent the music stops when an user click to it! can anyone help me please!

Comment: You have to show us your code. We don't even know in what language or IDE this is done in

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is complete, commented and tested example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
      // Add actual page to history
      history.pushState(null, null, location.pathname)

      // Register back button click
      window.onpopstate = function (e) {
        // Prevent default action on back button click
        e.preventDefault()
        // Add actual page to history again
        history.pushState(null, null, location.pathname)
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I put it in html head it doesnt work, thanks for reply!

Comment: You should explain a what your solution does. Code only answers are discouraged.